# SSH forwarding through NAT times out for one machine, but not another

Tags: ssh, nat, forwarding

This just started happening a few weeks ago seemingly out of the blue. Essentially, I have my home router setup to forward SSH to my home server. I can SSH into my server just fine from outside, but when I try to forward anything over SSH (with the `-L` flag) the connection hangs after 100-300kb are sent.

Here are some details:

- TP Link Archer C2300 router with stock firmware
- Home server running Ubuntu 18.04

I've simplified the problem for testing fixes. First I ssh into my home machine and forward some arbitrary port. Then I use netcat to dump data on that port to a file:

```
# make a tunnel into my network:
remote_host$ ssh -L 9999:localhost:9999 myhostname.whatever.com
myhostname$ nc -l 9999 > test.junk
```

In a separate shell I'm then dumping data through that forward:

```
remote_host$ cat /dev/urandom | nc localhost 9999
```

Here's what I observe:

- `test.junk` is created and grows to between 100-300kb and then stops
- The SSH connection locks up
- Eventually it times out or I get a "connection reset by peer" (or I just kill it from another shell)
- Other SSH connections to the same machine are fine

Here is what I tried to narrow down the scope of the problem:

- I tried the same trick within the network (no NAT). **This works just fine!**
- I tried changing the NAT to point to another host inside the network (rule out the router entirely). **This works great!**
- I tried fully disabling the firewall (iptables) on the host in question. **No luck.**
- `ssh -vvv` just stops showing output (no messages about a dropped connection or anything)
- Running `sshd` in debug mode (`sshd -ddd`) also shows nothing notable
- SSH client connection with `IPQoS=throughput` has no effect

This seems to only happen with SSH forwarding. The same host is running a Plex server and that works just fine from outside the network. I also have some security cameras in my home that can stream to their app with no problems (not going via the host in question).

How can I debug this?

Comment: Is it possible that your are exhausting ALL free space on a disk where you write your `test.junk` file and this is a reason for this behaviour? Additionally while we are on it - do you have enough free space in /tmp and /var/tmp?

Comment: @Tomek that's a good question. I don't think I could be running out of space though, because running the same test within my network works (data gets written to `test.junk` until I kill the writing process). Meanwhile both `/tmp` and `/var/tmp` are just on my root partition, which has about 300gb free.

Comment: Interesting. I would try to rule out /dev/urandom first (to little entropy on remote host, use /dev/zero or some other file instead), remote host itself (can you reproduce from different remote host through the NAT?) and then ssh port forwarding (just pipe through the tunnel, don't use port forwards).

Comment: I've simplified this test for repeatability, but I first noticed the problem when forwarding HTTP over SSH would stop loading the page after a few bytes came through. I have tried forwarding to another host inside the NAT, and that works fine. Therefore I think the problem is entirely on the remote host itself. I just have no idea how to debug it. I don't know enough about TCP to compare `tcpdump` traces I'm afraid.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with path MTU discovery... You may want to have a look at TCPMSS module for iptables and experiment with --clamp-mss-to-pmtu or --set-mss options for the connection between your remote and router. Unfortunately this is breakage somewhere along the path and iptables is merely a workaround, not a solution (if this is the case). Is the connection by any chance IPv6 tunnelled at one (or both) end? If so, try to rule this out as well.

Comment: I've disabled ipv6 in my network so I don't think that's it. Incidentally since my last post I reinstalled my entire OS from scratch and I'm still getting the same problem. It must be a hardware issue. I'm going to try installing the proprietary drivers for my NIC when I get a chance.